# Завершение процессов, по условию, из скрипта bash

Tags: linux, bash, скрипт

Нужно найти и завершить все процессы, не являющиеся лидерами сессий, и PID
которых >= N. 
Попробовал сделать попытку, но уже понял, что рассуждал неправильно:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((a = $1; a<=`ps -d | wc -l`; a++))
do
kill -9 $a
done
```

Прошу помочь разобраться с решением.

Comment: условие " не являющиеся лидерами сессий" и "не id последнего" НЕ одно и тоже. пожалуйста. уточните вопрос.

Comment: Я просто думал, что смогу перебрать процессы по id. Думал, что номер  процесса соответствует его id, но уже понял, что ошибся.

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать программу, как написано в первом предложении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант заготовки:

```
#!/bin/bash

N=10000
for pid in $(ps -A -o pid=)
do
    if [ "$pid" -gt "$N" ]
    then
        if [ "$(ps -o ppid= -p $pid)" -gt "1" ]
        then
            kill -9 $pid
        fi
    fi
done
```

А дальше сами.

Идея такая: берем pid-ы всех процессов, выбираем только те, что больше N, проверяем кто у процесса родитель, если это не процесс init(1), то считаем, что этот процесс дочерний от какого-то другого, и "киляем" его.

**Update**.

Поправочка прилетела. Речь ведь о Session ID, а не PPID.
Поэтому надо переписать скрипт где сравниваются PID и SID процесса, если они равны - то это мастер процесс, а если SID процесса отличается от его PID, то считаем его дочерним и убиваем.

Хотя тут есть проблема. Если "мастер" процесс был сам форкнут от другого процесса, который потом завершил работу, то мы получим, что PID != SID

```
 PID  PPID   SID COMMAND
 7735     1  7734 zabbix_agentd
 7737  7735  7734  \_ zabbix_agentd
 7738  7735  7734  \_ zabbix_agentd
 7739  7735  7734  \_ zabbix_agentd
 7740  7735  7734  \_ zabbix_agentd
 7741  7735  7734  \_ zabbix_agentd
```

"Мастер" zabbix_agentd имеет разные значения PID и SID и тогда надо смотреть на его PPID. Если он равен 1, то считаем его "мастером".

Comment: но лидер сессии - это когда `PID == SID`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor ваша правда. а я что-то на parent pid зациклился.

Comment: в if лучше поменяете условие или снизу напишите с SID.  так было бы лучше